# How to display the information of the customer who has the most 'use' in 'audit' table (Stored Procedure)

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin

How to display the information of the customer who has the most 'use' in 'audit' table.

problem i dont know how to get information customer.

```html
  select * from audit where used=
(select MAX(used) from audit)
```

audit table

[image]

customer table

[image]

Comment: Hint:  `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort your subquery highest to lowest and then take the first row with `LIMIT 1`.

---

```
Select *
FROM customer_table
WHERE customer_ID = (
                     SELECT customer_ID
                     FROM audit_table
                     ORDER BY USED DESC
                     LIMIT 1
                     )
```

*You may want to consider what happens if two customers have the same value in `USED`. It looks like there is a tie between `C001` & `C002` but this query will only return one customer*

Answer (score 0):

This will select the first record from the result set ordered by used in descending order.

```
Select TOP 1 *
from audit
order by used desc
```

Comment: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  This answer would benefit from an explanation.